# How to bind tokenData parameters of stripe.createToken() to inputs with ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create charge using a token created with stripe elements on the front end. I want to add the customers address by binding the different properties of tokenData with ngmodel to inputs, then passing the tokenData object as the second argument of the createToken() method.

```
//component.html

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="name" name="name">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address_line1" placeholder="adress line 1" name="address">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address_line2" placeholder="adress line 2" name="address">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address_city" placeholder="City" name="city">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address_state" placeholder="State" name="state">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address_country" placeholder="Country" name="country">

  <button (click)="submitForm()">Submit Payment</button>
```

```
//component.ts

  public tokenData = {
    name: '',
    address_line1: '',
    address_line2: '',
    address_city: '',
    address_state: '',
    address_zip: undefined,
    address_country: ''
  };

public submitForm = () => {
    this.stripe.createToken(this.card, this.tokenData).then(res => {
      if(res.error){
        console.log(res.error.message);
      }
      else {
        this.stripeTokenHandler(res.token).subscribe();
        console.log(res.token);
      }
    });
  };
  public stripeTokenHandler(t){
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/charge`, t);
  };
```

but when I submit the form the token gets logged to the console with the tokenData parameters empty, which means that the inputs aren't getting binding properly to tokenData. How can this be done?

Comment: well... all your props are inside the `tokenData`, so that is what you should bind to your view.

Comment: maybe just start by reading the documentation on how binding works: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngmodel-two-way-binding

Comment: @AJT82 you mean like `[(ngmodel)]="tokenData.address_line1" `instead of just adress_line1 by itself?

Comment: Yes exactly! :) Except remember uppercase `M` in `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: @AJT82 that doesnt work, i get the error "cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: where are you intializing `tokenData`? Seems `tokenData` is `undefined` and thus you are getting that error. It shouldn't give that error if `tokenData` is properly initialized on component creation.

Comment: @AJT82 i did properly initialize it int thhhe  component.ts and component.html to bind to tokenData.property instead of just property, but i am still getting blank address values in the token result.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding to the properties of the tokenData, add tokenData to all your bindings like [(ngModel)]="tokenData.address_line1"

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tokenData.name" placeholder="name" name="name">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tokenData.address_line1" placeholder="adress line 1" name="address">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tokenData.address_line2" placeholder="adress line 2" name="address">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tokenData.address_city" placeholder="City" name="city">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tokenData.address_state" placeholder="State" name="state">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tokenData.address_country" placeholder="Country" name="country">
```